# how to use .isAlive() onn Threading Class

Tags: python, multithreading, button, tkinter

I have Gui that has seperate threads however I need one of the threads to become active on a button press, my problem is when I press the button it creates an infinite loop that constantly generates new threads.

So I need to check whether the thread `.isAlive()` and if so pass, if not launch the thread:

```
if ThreadedTask.isAlive() == True:
        pass
    else:
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        ThreadedTask(self.queue).start()
```

but when I do this I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1437, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./2trans.py", line 539, in RecvBtn_Click
    if ThreadedTask.isAlive() == True:
TypeError: unbound method isAlive() must be called with ThreadedTask instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Could some one please advise what is causing this? I've added the full class and button function below for completion-ness sake:

```
class ThreadedTask(Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        proc = Popen("receivetest -f=/dev/pcan33".split(), stdout = PIPE)
        if terminated == 1:
            proc.kill()

        payload = iter(proc.stdout.readline, "")
        for line in payload:
            if line[0].isdigit():
                splitline = line.split()
                self.dictAdd(splitline)


    def dictAdd(self, info):

        global mydict

        can_ID = info[4]

        p = PCANmsg()

        p.dlc        = int(info[5])
        p.CANtime    = float(info[0])
        p.hdata0     = info[6]  
        p.hdata1     = info[7]
        p.hdata2     = info[8]
        p.hdata3     = info[9]
        p.hdata4     = info[10]
        p.hdata5     = info[11]
        p.hdata6     = info[12]
        p.hdata7     = info[13]
        p.timing     = 1

        if can_ID in mydict.keys():
            q = mydict[can_ID]
            p.COUNT = q.COUNT + 1
            p.PCANperiod = p.CANtime - q.CANtime
        else:
            p.COUNT = 1
            p.PCANperiod = 0.0

        mydict[can_ID] = p

        s = '%06X : %3d   %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\t %8.2F %8d ' %\
               (int(can_ID,16),
                p.dlc,
                int(p.hdata0, 16),
                int(p.hdata1, 16),
                int(p.hdata2, 16),
                int(p.hdata3, 16),
                int(p.hdata4, 16),
                int(p.hdata5, 16),
                int(p.hdata6, 16),
                int(p.hdata7, 16),
                p.PCANperiod,
                p.COUNT)

        self.queue.put(s)
```

button function:

```
def RecvBtn_Click(self):        

        if ThreadedTask.isAlive() == True:
            pass
        else:
            self.queue = Queue.Queue()
            ThreadedTask(self.queue).start()

        try:

            info = self.queue.get(0)
            info_split = info.split()

            if self.RecvList.size() <  len(mydict):

                for _i in mydict.keys():
                    self.RecvList.insert("end",'%06X : %3d   %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\t %8.2F %8d ' %\
                       (int(_i,16),
                        mydict[_i].dlc,
                        int(mydict[_i].hdata0, 16),
                        int(mydict[_i].hdata1, 16),
                        int(mydict[_i].hdata2, 16),
                        int(mydict[_i].hdata3, 16),
                        int(mydict[_i].hdata4, 16),
                        int(mydict[_i].hdata5, 16),
                        int(mydict[_i].hdata6, 16),
                        int(mydict[_i].hdata7, 16),
                        mydict[_i].PCANperiod,
                        mydict[_i].COUNT))

            else:
                for i, listbox_entry in enumerate(self.RecvList.get(0, "end")):
                    list_split = listbox_entry.split()
                    if list_split[0] == info_split[0]:
                        self.RecvList.delete(i)
                        self.RecvList.insert(i, info)

                    else:
                        continue
                   #     self.RecvList.insert("end", info)

            self.window.after(20, self.RecvBtn_Click)

        except Queue.Empty:
            self.window.after(100, self.RecvBtn_Click)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call isAlive() on a specific Thread object... If you haven't created one yet then you can't call isAlive(). Keep the Thread object in a variable initialized to None and instead of checking isAlive() check if this variable is None - if so assign it a new ThreadedTask object and start it. When the Thread terminates re-assign this variable to None.

Comment: Showing a concrete example can also be useful.